# How to add an object array in cache using ehcache, wherein each object has multiple fields?

Tags: arrays, object, ehcache

I am trying to include an object array in cache using cache.put() statement. What would be the procedure to do that?

Comment: `for (Object o : objects) {cache.put(new Element(o, o);}` -- if you override `hashCode()` and `equals()` by id, it will work.

Comment: Dear Sasha, I am not able to understand the solution you just posted. Could you please exemplify. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know preconditions and your intention. You question is too uncertain and regards specific library. Could you please edit your question adding some code and explaining better your purpose?

Comment: I basically want to add an object array in cache. I am using ehcache. I did some research on the web but couldn't get ahead from cache.put (). If suppose I have an object array Employees, with fields salary, name, address, etc.. I want to cache all this information for say 100 employees. How do I do that using ehcache? Thanks a lot for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose your `Employee` class has `Object getId()` method which returns ID by which every particular instance of `Employee` can be uniquely identified.

`Cache#put()` requires `Element`, which requires ID and object itself in its constructor, so:

```
for (Employee e : employees) {
    cache.put(new Element(e.getId(), e));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. What would be the corresponding cache.get() structure if I need to access individual field element...like salary of employee x.

Comment: I believe it would be `Employee e = cache.get(id).getObjectValue(); Double salary = e.getSalary();` =)